# Is javascript not executed on mobile devices if the page is not currently shown?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, ajax

I'm tracking the time users spend reading contents on my website. To consider the user is actually reading, I do a first ajax request after 10 seconds the page has been loaded. Then, I set the `beforeunload` event to trigger another ajax request to notice the user has finished reading.

There is a problem when the user opens another page in a different tab, but the page I'm tracking is not closed, so I set I timer after 10 min to trigger the end reading ajax and unset the `beforeunload`. This makes browsers to send the signal when the page is open, but the tab hasn't been closed.

However, I've noticed that on mobile devices (Android, iPhone and iPad), the timer set to automatically notice finish reading after 10 min doesn't get executed. So, I'm wondering if: **do mobile devices stop executing javascript when the page is not shown on the screen to save battery?** If so, how could I run the timer and trigger the ajax request even though the page is not shown (but still open)?

```
function endReading(id) {
  $.ajax({
    url: "{% url 'end_read_content' %}",
    type: "post",
    data: {"id": id},
    async: false,
  });
}
setTimeout(function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "{% url 'new_read_content' %}",
    type: "post",
    data: {"content_slug": "{{ content.slug }}"},
    success: function(data) {
      $(window).on('beforeunload', function() {endReading(data)});
      setTimeout(function() {
        endReading(data);
        $(window).off('beforeunload');
      }, 600000);
    }
  });
}, 10000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setTimeout use requestAnimationFrame

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.requestAnimationFrame

By specification this function will not call when the window is not in focus.

http://caniuse.com/requestanimationframe

More details here:

http://www.paulirish.com/2011/requestanimationframe-for-smart-animating/

It is passed an int of the current running time, so your function should check that and only send an ajax request every so many seconds.

In response to the 'can I use this for not animations' question:

Absolutely you can use it for whatever you want. Another option

```
var lastUsageTime = 0;
var lastSentTime = 0;

window.requestAnimationFrame(function(t){
 lastUsageTime = t;
});

setTimeout(function(){ 
 if(lastUsageTime - lastSentTime > 10000){
//do ajax
lastSentTime = lastUsageTime
 }
});
```

Comment: As I can see, this seems to be used for animations, but I need it to permorm an Ajax call. Would it be safe to use this function in my case? Furthermore, this seems to be a loop, but I don't need a loop at all. I just need to execute code once, after a fixed time.